# Blank page after deploying to heroku?

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework

Recently I have created a simple project using:

1. Django Rest  https://branches-shiv.herokuapp.com/branches/
2. Angular  https://branches-front-shiv.herokuapp.com/

I have two separate folders for both Django and Angular, also connected both successfully, they are just working fine locally but after deploying to Heroku Angular which is frontend showing blank page except heading. here is the link. https://branches-front-shiv.herokuapp.com/

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/angular'));
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname +
        '/dist/myapp/index.html'));
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

**package.json**

```
 "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.3",
    "npm": "6.14.9"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.5",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.2.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.14",
    "ng2-order-pipe": "^0.1.5",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.5",
```

**api.servcie.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ShareService {
  readonly APIUrl = "https://branches-shiv.herokuapp.com";
  readonly PhotoUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getBranchList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.APIUrl + '/branches/');
  }

  getAllNames(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.APIUrl + '/branches/');
  }
}
```

Please tell me if any other file you might want to take a look at.
here is how it is working on localhost:

[image]

Comment: what problem you getting can you provide some more information

Comment: It is showing a blank page that just  it. No other errors. I have created a table but I am not  seeing any table there.

Comment: but when i opened your link that you provide is showing me  object of branch

Comment: https://branches-front-shiv.herokuapp.com/ look at this link there supposed be a table with table header like name, state, city etc. and table content. It is working fine in localhost but I can't see anything in deployment one. Updated the question take a look.